# Issue with PCI Scan Failing Because of Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hoping someone can help me here. Long story short I'm working with a client that is using Trustwave as their firewall provider and for their PCI scans. This particular location continues to fail their scans with the same two errors over and over for "jquery"

jQuery Core rquickExpr variable
with Cross-Site Scripting
Vulnerability, CVE-2012-6708

and

jQuery Cross-Domain
Asynchronous JavaScript and
Extensible Markup Language
Request Cross-site Scripting
Vulnerability, CVE-2015-9251

Now the issue here is that the network being scanned is a point of sale system. Why is this happening? Isn't this a script library for web content developers? the scans indicate that there is TCP communication over port 80 related to jquery but that's simply not true when I check using the command prompt. There is no program running that should be using this or anything java related. How can I find what is using this script library?

Another snippet from the scan indicated the following for the failures.

Evidence:
Match: '1.7.1' is less than '3.0.0'
Remediation:
Upgrade jquery to version 3.0.0 or higher.

Comment: It seems that you need to do a couple things. 1. Have your dev team update jQuery as they are using an old version. This could have some undesirable outcomes and require some heavy refactors from the dev teams though, so it may be a long process. 2. Have the team check to make sure they aren't doing any `$.get() $.post()` to any HTTP addresses (HTTPS is Ok). This is where you'll get those communication over port 80 messages.

Comment: Does _...the network being scanned..._  mean a file system folder/directory was discovered with that old version of jquery?  If yes,  and that folder/dir is not related to an active web app, then the file system owner needs to do some clean up.

Comment: In addition, all of those CVE codes return back that jQuery prior to 3.0 is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Just have your dev team upgrade to 3.0 or greater then the problem should be solved. If I remember correctly, you get 9 months or more to remediate the problem as long as you give them your gameplan.

Comment: @RyanC What Dev team specifically though? Our devs for the POS software provider?? Not all of our locations are actively scanning right now but the ones that are, not that many of them are failing with this exact error so it's most likely some other program running on the computers??

Comment: @AndrewS I'm not positive but it's probably just the network itself. It may be looking at files/folders but I've already done a manual search for jquery and deleted all files in the results, cached/saved webpage for offline use. 


There is the possibility that it's a false positive as SonicWall had this very problem with their scans a few years ago. Problem is the teams over at Trustwave are being very uncooperative.

Comment: @JohnTownsend Whichever team owns the file/folder/software/location of where that old version of jQuery resides. I'm assuming/hoping your company has some sort of portfolio on who owns each box or software? They are the ones that need engaged and informed that they need to update jQuery to a newer than 3.0 version

Comment: @RyanC that makes sense but one of the issues here is that I have no way to know where jquery is, where and how it's being used. The only software vendors we have right now are the POS software provider and Trustwave's scanning utilities. I've checked previously with the devs for our POS software and they don't use jquery for anything. So how can I find out what on this specific computer is using the script library?

Comment: @JohnTownsend Did the Trustwave scanning utilities give you any detail on where it found the information? I would be surprised if it only said "Hey, you have an issue." and then didn't tell you WHERE exactly that issue was.

Comment: @RyanC Believe it or not but it doesn't. It only has basic information such as the vulnerability type, details about the vulnerability etc etc. It mentions TCP port 80 as well. I wish I had an easy way to post screenshots or the entire results of the scan. We've been working with Trustwave to figure this out but it's like pulling teeth getting anything out of them and they've thrown their hands in there and not assisting. Just telling us hey here's the problem now fix it if you want us to pass you Which is extremely disappointing since we have 1,700 locations paying for their terrible service.

Comment: I'm contacting their support at CyberSourceSupport@Trustwave.com for this same reason, I don't expect them to help us :( We dispute this finding as false positive every time, but we don't have 1700 locations, we are less than 10. 

Their scans don't show the location of the finding, it's so frustrating.

Comment: @AgustinGarzon It turns out the issue was with insecure protocols using Jquery on the log in page of local security cameras. They were placed on the modem instead of the DMZ. Also just as a heads up when Trustwave sets up thie scanning tools to run on the network they have to have a backdoor VPN setup. Their own VPN into the system was causing alot of false positives on the scan and they were completely clueless as to what the issue was and WE had to figure it out. So if you are seeing that weak SSH on port 22. There's your answer.